# Codeception\Exception\InjectionException : Service di is not defined and can't be accessed from a test

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

Testing started at 下午5:45 ...

```
/usr/local/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9001 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /var/www/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration --filter "/(::testMerlinTemplate)( .*)?$/" tests\jobs\SettlementJobTest /var/www/example/tests/unit/jobs/SettlementJobTest.php --teamcity
PHPUnit 7.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Codeception\Exception\InjectionException : Service di is not defined and can't be accessed from a test
 /var/www/example/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Test/Metadata.php:191
 /var/www/example/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Test/Unit.php:47
```

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to run a Codeception unit test using phpunit, the `di` (dependency injection) service is not available in the latter. You should run the test using the Codeception CLI, e.g.:

```
codecept run /var/www/example/tests/unit/jobs/SettlementJobTest.php
```

Comment: The test I'm getting this error on has run fine many times in PhpStorm, but is now throwing this error.

Comment: @BobRay you should check what PhpStorm is executing under the hood, most likely it reverted back to a phpunit run configuration (which is the default for unit tests); you might need to (re-)add a Codeception run configuration.

Comment: I had issue, that I was echoing version of my software in `bootstrap.php`, this confused PHPStorm and was unable to detect codeception version and reverted to phpunit.